# Sort the data table of an Excel chart by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating lots of charts on VBA 100% programmatically.

A part of my code does this on the charts:

```
   ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataTableWithLegendKeys)
```

But the resulting data table changes the order of the original data, even if it was previously sorted, which is obviously an error of Microsoft:

[image: sample1]

It makes no sense. The data is ordered desc, but the data table on the chart shows it asc.
I know that I could change the order manually right clicking the chart and doing it manually this way, one by one:

[image: sample2]

But, as we can see, this isn't programmatically way. I am working on auto-generate hundreds of charts, with different data on every single one.

Macro recording does not register this kind of changes. What could I do to solve this Excel error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when a chart is created or data-updated, it reverts the order/sorting.
So, what I did was copy on a 2nd table all the data, and invert the sorting of that data on VBA. So, when I create the chart from that other desc order/sorting, shows like asc, or vice versa if you want to.